# AngularJS updating child component when parent element changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope

I'm working on a an existing Angular application (1.4.3) and I'm trying to break things up into components that can be more re-usable and allow for a better upgrade path to Angular 2.

I've got a child component that takes an input from the parent and displays a table. In the table, that input has been plugged into various mathematical formulas and displays each of the resulting numbers. My problem is that when I update the parent value, the child component doesn't reflect the update. I thought `bindToController` was supposed to make is so that I didn't have to put a watch on the input. I also noticed things get weird if I'm using `ng-model` vs `ng-bind` in the template. Can anyone explain to me what's going on here and why?

Here's an example.  http://jsbin.com/yoqenahini/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: any answer to this one? can you comment on any of the answers, why they helped/didn't help etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just adding a `$watch` on the input after coming across this comment chain. It's working great. I was just overly concerned about watches.

http://teropa.info/blog/2015/10/18/refactoring-angular-apps-to-components.html#comment-2446653932

In reality, this works great and still feels better because the watch is inside the component opposed to on the page controller.

There is a quirk though if you are using controllerAs which I had to discover here. 
https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/#ironing-a-quirk

Answer (score 0):

The reason the value isn't being updated in the child directive is that you are assigning the value to a new variable here:

```
this.item2 = this.item + 25;
```

and then your input is binding to the new value `item2`.

Here's a fork of your code, I added a second input in the child directive that binds to `item`. When you change the parent value it also changes.

http://jsbin.com/carolitajo/1/edit?html,js,output

So if you just use the `item` property directly in your child controller you should be all set. Angular isn't going to re-run your assignment to `item2` every time the parent value changes.

Comment: I got a downvote too haha the guys here are crazy, that is why I think a lot when I want to post an answer. You never know, your answer and mine are valid, but they don't care, they don't answer anything, they just downvote, they are like monkeys.

Answer (score -1):

what about

```
$scope.$broadcast( "parentCtrlUpdateChild", args );
```

and then

in your child

```
$scope.$on("parentCtrlUpdateChild", function(event, args) {
  ...
});
```

see Todd Motto's explanation https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

see this Bin I prepared for you

http://jsbin.com/zinuqikemo/edit?html,js,output

```
function parent() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div><div><input type="text" ng-model="item"/></div><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>',
    controllerAs: 'pctrl',
    transclude: true,
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.item = 25;
      $scope.hola = function() {
        $scope.item = $scope.item + 1;
        $scope.$broadcast('hola', $scope.item);
      };
    }
  };
}

function child() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      item: '='
    },
    template: '<div><div><input type="text" ng-model="item2"/><div></div></div></div>',
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'cctrl',
    controller: function($scope) {      
      $scope.$on('hola', function (event, args) {
        $scope.item2 = args + 25;
      });
    }
  };
}
```

and in your HTML just add this

```
<button ng-click="hola()">HOLA</button>
```